# How to add respective user data in firestore after login using angular 9?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angular9

I want to add individual users data in firestore and I don't know how to do this. I am a beginner.
I couldn't found any appropriate solutions. What should i change in my code..

**TS File**

```
onSubmit() {
 if(this.rmForm.value.id == null){
    this.firestore.collection('rms').add(data);
    this.toastr.success("Successfully Saved",'',{timeOut:900})
    this.resetForm();
  }
   else{
    this.firestore.doc('rms/' + this.rmForm.value.id).update(data);
    this.toastr.success("Successfully Updated",'',{timeOut:900})
    this.resetForm();
  }
}

 resetForm() {
  this.rmForm = this.fb.group({
  id:null,
  UName: ['', Validators.required],
  City: ['', Validators.required],
  Address: ['', Validators.required], 
  })
 }
```

**HTML File**

```
<form [formGroup]="rmForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="form-row">       
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputName">Your Name<small> *</small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="UName" placeholder="Your name">
        <label class="text-danger small" *ngIf="rmForm.get('UName').touched && rmForm.get('UName').errors?.required">Required</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputCity">City<small> *</small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="City" placeholder="City">
        <label class="text-danger small" *ngIf="rmForm.get('City').touched && rmForm.get('City').errors?.required">Required</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputAddress">Address<small> *</small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Address" placeholder="Address">
        <label class="text-danger small" *ngIf="rmForm.get('Address').touched && rmForm.get('Address').errors?.required">Required</label>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!rmForm.valid"> SUBMIT </button>
```

Is anything that i have to add/change in my code to store individual user data in firestore. Should I change Rules in Firebase?

**Auth Servive.ts** *Updated code*

```
SignIn(email, password) {
   return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.router.navigate(['home']);
     });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.toastr.error("Email or Password doesnot match");        
   })
 }
```

**Login Component.ts**

```
 onSubmit() {
  this.authService.SignIn(this.signInForm.value.email, 
  this.signInForm.value.password)
  }
```

I want to get a registered user profile in home component.

**Home component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getUsers();
 }

    getUser(user){
      this.afs.collection('users').doc(credential.user.uid).set({
       uid: user.uid,
       email: user.email,
       contact: user.contact,
       password: user.password
     });
    }
```

> Error:Cannot find name 'credential'. Did you mean
> 'Credential'?ts(2552) lib.dom.d.ts(3665, 13): 'Credential' is declared
> here.

Comment: What is the purpose of your form ? Is it related to authenticated users ? You might whant to create a firebase user and use the uid of this newly created user as a document ID for the collection holding users data.

Comment: @QuentinFonck This form is to record user data after user login. Every user can save its own data in firestore. So how do i save and get user data.. Just like Facebook (Login and get own profile)

Comment: @QuentinFonck I have updated my code above. I have pasted your code in home.component.ts but I am not getting Logged in user data in console. What is I am missing ??

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the AngularFireAuth service and call eather:

- `signInWithPopup(provider)` (register/login using facebook/google/twitter) or
- `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)` for register using mail or
- `signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pwd)` to login with an email.

All these functions will return a `firebase.auth.UserCredential` that will give you access to the auth user uid. Use this id to create/update data related to the specific user:

```js
this.afs.collection('user_collection').doc(credential.user.uid).set({
    // your user data
});
```

To know if your need to create or update, you can check `credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`. It will return true if user just got created in the auth DB.
To know the current authenticated user, use the **authState**. It's an hot observable from which you can retrieve your user uid and fetch your user data in firestore:

```js
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap((authUser) => {
       return (!!authUser) ? 
           this.afs.collection('user_collection').doc(authUser.uid).valueChanges():
           of(null)
    })
)
```

### EDIT

You should create your user data once signin is done:

#### auth.service.ts

```js
signIn(email, password): Promise<void> {
   return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => { // result is your user credential here
      return this.afs.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).set({
       uid: result.user.uid,
       email: email
     });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.toastr.error("Email or Password doesnot match");        
   })
 }
```

#### login.component.ts

```js
onSubmit() {
 this.authService.signIn(
    this.signInForm.value.email,
    this.signInForm.value.password
 ).then(() => this.router.navigate(['home'])); // go to home if succeeded
}
```

in home component, you subscribe to the authState and get your user data:

#### home.component

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        switchMap(authUser => { // authUser == null if no user logged in
            return (!!authUser) ? this.getUser(authUser.uid) : of(null)
        })
    ).subscribe(user => console.log('your user: ', user));
   
 }

 getUser(uid){
     // set method is for writing data, use valueChanges to get data
     return this.afs.collection('users').doc(uid).valueChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I got Error: id: user.uid, email: user.email ...Cannot find the user in Auth.Service.ts  and your user undefined  (in the console)

Comment: You obviously need to pass the data coming from your form in the onSubmit to the signin method. I will update the answer.

Comment: I am passing email and password to SignIn method.  I have only password and email.  User ??

Comment: You put contact in the set method in your home component so I asumed you were using other inputs in your form. Should be good now. I also removed the password field in the set method, you should never save a password in plain text in a DB. Firebase authentication already handles that for you.